# How to create SharedMemory from pickle directly?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.8

So I'm writing a multiprocessing program, composed of 2 pools. The first pool will send their result to the second pool through a Queue.

**My Aim:** An efficient way of transferring the result from the first pool to the second pool.

Since the size of the first pool's result might be quite big, in the order of tens of MB, I'd like to use [SharedMemory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). I'm using Python 3.8 anyways so backward compatibility with <=3.7 is not needed.

Currently, the piece of code in the first pool is like this:

```
    # result_object is pickle-able, no probs here.
    pickled_result = pickle.dumps(result_object)
    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=len(pickled_result))
    shm.buf[0:] = pickled_result
    job_queue.put(shm)
```

I'm concerned with the line `shm.buf[0:]`, from what I know (CMIIW), that line copies from `pickled_result` into the `memoryview` buffer of `SharedMemory`.

And with `result_object` in the 10s of MB, that would be time wasted.

**My Questions:**

Is there a way to create `SharedMemory` directly from `pickle` so that the copy doesn't need to happen?

Or, is there a Better Way™ to implement what I aim for?